# Can i format txt files from within python

Tags: python, text, output

now pleased don't get me wrong on this, but im just curious whether I can get a text file and then find out how many lines within that text file have been written on, and thus use that number to print selective data from every few lines. Also could I use python to find specific words within the text file that are evenly apart for example within the text file if everything was written like this

name:> Ben

Score:> 2

name:> Ethan

Score:> 8

name:> James

Score:> 0

would it be possible for me to search the text file, for the string 'name:>' (and then save whatever comes infront of it, if possible to a variable) or seeing as they're all equally spaced could I save the specific score of one person to a variable with their name (as everything in front would be equally spaced), without having to open the txt file at all.

If all of this sounds completely impossible or if any of you have received any vague ideas as to what im talking about (in which case im in awe of your abilities of comprehension from this badly worded example), please give me any thoughts or ideas on how to format text files to create variables.

if all the above seems too complex could someone please just tell me wether its possible to analyse how many lines within a text file have been written on, from there ive got a vague idea on how to create my program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression (RE) to search the text file as a string, then find out where the existing value is you want to change in the text file and write it.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply, is it possible to instead of changing the existing value, to instead save the value to a variable within python :)

Comment: Even better actually is to use rfind which provides a location of the search string, then you can slice out so many characters after, strip whitespace, and assign that to a variable.

name_location = TextFileString.rfind('name:>')
name = TextFileString[name_location:10(however many)].rstrip

Answer (score 0):

To do what you are asking, I would personally use the built-in `re` module, as follows:

```
import re
with open("foo.txt", "r") as foo:
    contents = foo.read()

results = re.search("foo-bar", contents).group()
print(results)
```

That should do what you are looking for.